# Finding range of $(a+d)(b+c)$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Four positive real nos. satisfy the equation:

$a+b+c+d = 2$

Let $M = (a+c)(d+b).$ Find the range of $M.$

I try for values, and find that minimum cannot be less than or equal to 0.

The maximum will be close to 1.

But how do I find maximum apart from trial and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a+c=x>0$ and $b+d=y>0,$ Then Given $a+b+c+d=x+y=2$

and we have to calculate Range of $(a+c)(b+d) = xy>0$

So Using $\bf{A.M\geq G.M\;,}$ We get $$\frac{x+y}{2}\geq \sqrt{xy}\Rightarrow xy\leq 1$$

So range of $$0<xy\leq 1$$

Answer (score 0):

In such question we can use concept of maxima/minima.
$$\text{Let } x = a+c $$ $$ \implies b+d = 2-x$$  $$\therefore M = x(2-x)$$

$$\dfrac{dM}{dx} = \dfrac{d}{dx}(2x - x^2) = 0$$ $$\implies x = 1\text{ and }\therefore M = 1$$

With this, we get max value as 1. So the range is: $M \in (0,1]$